# PHP MVC Fat controller VS Fat model

Tags: php, validation, model-view-controller, error-handling

Lets say I have a basic HTML form for sending e-mail:

```
<form action="contactSubmit" method="POST">
    <label for="name" class="italic">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" value="" maxlength="20" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <label for="email" class="italic">E-mail:</label>
    <input type="email" name="reply_to" value="" maxlength="255" required="required" />
    <label for="comments" class="italic">Comments:</label>
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="50" required="required"></textarea>
    <br />
    <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Send" />
</form>
```

Currently all validation is done in a controller:

```
// submit contact request
public function contactSubmit() {
    // process form if submitted
    if ( $this->formSubmit() ) {
        // validate input
        $name = isset($_POST['name']) && $this->validate($_POST['name'], null, 20) ? $_POST['name'] : null;
        $reply_to = isset($_POST['reply_to']) && $this->validate($_POST['reply_to'], 'email', 255) ? $_POST['reply_to'] : null;
        $message  = isset($_POST['message']) && $this->validate($_POST['message']) ? $_POST['message'] : null;

        // proceed if required fields were validated
        if ( isset( $name, $reply_to, $message ) ) {
            $to = WEBMASTER;
            $from = 'nobody@' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
            $reply_to = $name . ' <' . $reply_to . '>';
            $subject = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ' - Contact Form';

            // send message
            $mail = $this->model->build('mail');
            if ( $mail->send($to, $from, $reply_to, $subject, $message ) ) {
                $_SESSION['success'] = 'Your message was sent successfully.';
            } else {
                // preserve input
                $_SESSION['preserve'] = $_POST;

                // highlight errors
                $_SESSION['failed'] = 'The mail() function failed.';
            }
        } else {
            // preserve input
            $_SESSION['preserve'] = $_POST;

            // highlight errors
            if ( !isset( $name ) ) {
                $_SESSION['failed']['name'] = 'Please enter your name.';
            }
            if ( !isset( $reply_to ) ) {
                $_SESSION['failed']['reply_to'] = 'Please enter a valid e-mail.';
            }
            if ( !isset( $message ) ) {
                $_SESSION['failed']['message'] = 'Please enter your comments.';
            }
        }
    }

    $this->view->redirect('contact');
}
```

I want to move away from "fat controllers" and more towards "fat models", but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to cleanly transplant the validation from the preceding controller to the proceding model:

```
public function send( $to, $from, $reply_to, $subject, $message ) {
    // generic headers
    $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . PHP_EOL;
    $headers .= 'From: ' . $from . PHP_EOL; // should belong to a domain on the server
    $headers .= 'Reply-to: ' . $reply_to . PHP_EOL;

    // send message
    return mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
}
```

The form only has 3 required fields, while the model's method accepts 5. The descriptions of the form fields are different from the input names which makes it difficult to customize the error messages while keeping the model portable for use in other applications. It seems like every attempt I make ends up being ridiculously fat and still doesn't achieve the same flexibility I have with the initial approach.

Could someone please show me a clean way to move validation from the controller to the model while still keeping the flexibility of custom error messages and also keeping the portability of the model for use in other applications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MVC Validation Advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19351502/mvc-validation-advice)

Comment: The part of validation, that is tied to business logic, should happen within [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject). The data integrity checks should be handled  by storage abstractions. Controllers in MVC-like architectures has **NOTHING** to do with validation. Also, there are no "fat models". Model is not a class.

Comment: @tereško He refers to domain objects when he says models (entities, data objects , command objects, whatever objects you have in the domain layer) . But there aren't any mvc framework that actualy teach programmers how to build a domain layer . Laravel for example in it's docs is presenting a data driven aproach not DDD for the model layer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all , are you really using pure OOP ? Why would you use a model method with external data ? The model should work with it's own properties . A model object should not be instantiated if the data needed to create the object is not valid .

You need to create more layeres that would communicate with the model . For example you can have a modelFactories layer that can handle this validation . Let's say you have a user model , in the modelFactories layer you have a UserFactory . You could put here the validation logic . If the data needed to create the User model is not valid don't even create the model.

A more abstract way would be to add more layeres like a dataTransferObjects layer . Here you can have objects that transfer data to the model or model factories . Again you can put here the validation logic and you can then use the modelFactories to create a User model from a UserDTO object (User data transfer object).

The thing is that you should never create a model without preparing it's data before , like validating it . That's why a model should work with it's own properties and don't pass right in external data (only pass data to initialise the object).

You should read more about Domain Driven Design and design patterns .

So this way your model stay decoupled and you can reuse it in other applications .

Comment: So you're saying there is nothing wrong with the fat controller approach? Because that's exactly what I'm doing, validating the data before instantiating the model.

Comment: Yes I'm saying that validation is better on the controller's side than in the model . But the best would be to restructure your app by adding more layeres like i said above . Ofcourse this also depends :) if it's a small app (and no extensions will be needed) don't overthink how to structure it .

Answer (score 1):

I'd say neither should be fat. When dealing with HTML forms, I think it's the cleanest to have a `Form` object like `CommentForm` that has field objects (e.g., `EmailField extends Field`) that do their own field level validation.

If the form validates, then you are guaranteed to have clean data. The form can also create and return various models, which themselves would have also done validation at a member level. But nothing is fat... each bit only needs to know about the stuff that immediately concerns them.

The controller would look something like:

```
if ($form->validate($request->post())) {
  // grab the email model from the form
  $email = $form->getEmail();

  // assume $mailTransport implements some mailer interface
  if ($mailTransport->send($email) == true) {
    // sent email
    return $response->redirect('success');
  }
  else {
    // something unexpected happened
    $view->flashError('Unable to send email');
  }
}

$view->form = $form;
```

Every controller that processes ends up looking very similar and very clean. The models know nothing about HTML forms. It's an easy pattern to repeat over and over.

There are many ways to do this; the above just happens to be my favorite general purpose solution.